# How can i get process id of UNIX command i am triggering in a Perl script?

Tags: perl, unix

I am triggering a UNIX command in Perl script.

I need the process ID of the UNIX command.

For example if i trigger below UNIX command:

```
# padv -s adv.cfg > adv.out &
[1] 4550
```

My process ID is 4550.

```
# ps -ef | grep padv
root      4550  2810  0 16:28 pts/5    00:00:00 padv -s adv.cfg
root      4639  2810  0 16:29 pts/5    00:00:00 grep padv
```

How to capture that process ID in my Perl Script?

For example, i am triggering my command in Perl script like below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

qx(padv -s adv.cfg > adv.out &);
```

Comment: The process runs for long time so i want to run it in the background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`open()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html)

> Open returns nonzero on success, the undefined value otherwise. If the open involved a pipe, the return value happens to be the pid of the subprocess.

```
my $pid = open(my $ph, "-|", "padv -s adv.cfg > adv.out") or die $!;
```

reading output from `$ph` file handle instead of output redirect:

```
my $pid = open(my $ph, "-|", "padv -s adv.cfg") or die $!;
```

Comment: Opening a pipe already creates a fork. You should lose the `&`.

Comment: As mentioned, opening a pipe creates a fork, and so is already in the "background". No need for ampersand. You could also remove the redirect to adv.out and just read/process the output using the `$ph` file handle.

Answer (score 3):

Call [`fork`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fork.html) to create a child process. The process ID of the child process is returned to the parent process. The child process can then call [`exec`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html) to execute the program you want.